# GROUP BY two columns

Tags: mysql, select, update, group-by

I want to count two columns, but need to get the results of first column in one row.

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY country, type
```

This query gives me

```
country    type     COUNT(*)
Canada     first    22
Canada     second   42
Canada     third    15
Australia  second   23
Australia  third    18
```

but I need to get

```
country    type_first   type_second   type_third
Canada     22           42            15
Australia  23           18            0
```

as I want to update another table with these values, and with this row structure, I can update the country table row by row as I get from the above query.

```
UPDATE country SET first=x, second=x, third=x
```

NOTE: `type` column is `ENUM` with predefined values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want something like:

```
SELECT country
, sum(case when type = 'first' then 1 else 0 end) as type_first
, sum(case when type = 'second' then 1 else 0 end) as type_second
, sum(case when type = 'third' then 1 else 0 end) as type_third
FROM table1
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: This is more concise. +1 !!!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    country,
    SUM(IF(A.type='first' ,country_type_count,0)) type_first,
    SUM(IF(A.type='second',country_type_count,0)) type_second,
    SUM(IF(A.type='third' ,country_type_count,0)) type_third
FROM
(
    SELECT country, type, COUNT(*) country_type_count
    FROM table1 GROUP BY country, type
) A
GROUP BY country;
```

Comment: If you do the group by and count(*) in the subquery...you can't then SUM with IF...  You'd end up with a country and a sum of 1 for each type.

Comment: @rfusca You are right. I forget my `GROUP BY`.

Comment: If you're going to do it like that, you'd have to do `SUM(if(A.type='first',country_type_count,0))` and such.

Comment: @rfusca I was editing it as you commented. Thanks you the additional catch :-)